# ID appears twice in query when multiplied with different Prices

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to get the top 5 stations by Sales,
but I ran into the problem that one station appears twice if multiplied by a different price.

This is my query:

```sql
SELECT distinct b_id, count(t_start_id) * v_preis AS START_PRICE
  FROM bahnhof
 INNER JOIN tickets
    ON t_start_id = b_id
 INNER JOIN connections
    ON t_connection_id = v_id
 GROUP BY b_id, v_preis
 ORDER BY START_PRICE DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Which gives me the following result:

| b_id | START_PRICE |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 75 |
| 6 | 50 |
| 4 | 30 |
| 1 | 16 |
| 1 | 15 |

What i need though is:

| b_id | START_PRICE |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 75 |
| 6 | 50 |
| 1 | 31 |
| 4 | 30 |

I tried to group by ID only, but it didn't work since v_preis had to be in there too.

The price for 1 is 8 twice and 15 once, so I guess I have a problem with using different rows for one result.

I'm pretty new to SQL, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question,
thank you in advance!

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, `v_preis` is in the  expression in the select list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using `SUM()` aggregation along with only *grouping by id*?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT b_id, SUM(v_preis) AS start_price
  FROM bahnhof
  JOIN tickets
    ON t_start_id = b_id
  JOIN connections
    ON t_connection_id = v_id
 GROUP BY b_id
 ORDER BY START_PRICE DESC 
 LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: thank you very much! that solved it